# Is Stop loss available in Trading view version (v19)?

Tags: charts, tradingview-api

I want to know how I can setup stop loss in trading view (v19) Version.

Answer (score 0):

The TradingView Charting Library version 19 (CL v19) doesn't seem to provide built-in functionality specifically for setting a stop loss line on the chart, at least as far as publicly available information goes.